# Why does Tomcat return HTTP 404 when I try to run my webpage?

Tags: tomcat

I am using Eclipse to run a HTML webpage in Tomcat server. When I am trying to run the web page by clicking on *"Run on server"*, it's showing an error message:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
```

Screenshot of error message:
[image: Pics showing the entire scenario]

Tomcat is working fine:
[image: Pics to show Tomcat is working fine]

Comment: You are trying to access a tomcat private configuration file so getting a polite 404. Try using a simple jsp.

Comment: show your web.xml